# Is there any relationship between 'invertible' and 'diagonalizable'?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse, diagonalization

I'am a linear algebra beginner and I am confusing with invertible and diagonalizable.

From my understanding, invertible means non-singular and any of eigenvalue must not be 0. Diagonalizable means there must be N linearly independent eigenvectors.(Eventhough eigenvalue has 0, it seems possible to have N linearly independent eigenvectors. Right?)

Above are just single fraction of their property, and I cannot imagine bigger picture than this.

Is there any intuitive relation or theorem between 'invertible' and 'diagonalizable'?

Comment: There are invertible matrices which are not diagonalizable and there are diagonalizable matrices which are not invertible. There are matrices which are neither diagonalizable nor invertible.

Comment: The zero matrix is diagonalisable but not invertible, while $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ is invertible but not diagonalisable. So there is no immediate connection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> From my understanding, invertible means non-singular and any of eigenvalue must not be 0.

Exactly. In fact, a matrix is singular if and only if $0$ is its eigenvalue.

> Diagonalizable means there must be N linearly independent eigenvectors.(Eventhough eigenvalue has 0, it seems possible to have N linearly independent eigenvectors. Right?)

Correct. Even if an eigenvalue is $0$, a matrix can have $N$ linearly independent eigenvectors. For example, the zero matrix has $N$ linearly independent eigenvectors, because every vector is an eigenvector for the zero matrix.

---

> Is there any intuitive relation or theorem between 'invertible' and 'diagonalizable'?

Not directly, in the sense that one would imply another. You can have matrices in all four classes, i.e.

- *Invertible and diagonalizable.* An example of this is the idenity matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$.
- *Invertible and not diagonalizable.* The simples example would be $\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$.
- *Singular and diagonalizable.* The zero matrix $\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$. is the simplest example of this.
- *Singular and non-diagonalizable.* The simplest example is probably $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: how did you derive the example so fast? Do you have any intuition about diagonalizable matrix?

Comment: @DongukJu Practice, practice, practice. It builds intuition like nothing else. Also, I think learning about the Jordan form of a matrix helps build intuition about what "diagonalizable" really means, and why some matrices are not diagonalizable.